# Internal Server Error bitnami redmine

Tags: redmine, bitnami

I have a git integration problem with Redmine, I use the image of the BitNami hosted on Amazon server, someone has found himself in a similar error that could help me?
Thank you all for the attention!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In order to configure the Bitnami Redmine Stack wit GIT, you should take a look to the guide below:
https://docs.bitnami.com/google/apps/redmine/#how-to-configure-redmine-for-advanced-integration-with-git

Comment: ok, but that's exactly following this documentation that the error originated

Comment: In the pic seems to be a 500 error when cloning. If you paste any of the Gitlab logs here maybe can suggest any solution for this...